# Sass compilation using Compass on Cloud9?

Tags: sass, compass-sass, cloud9-ide

I am trying to compile my Sass on the Cloud9 (http://c9.io) IDE.  I have a Compass `config.rb` file, which I'd like to be adhered to.

The output of `sass -h` within the terminal states that a `--compass` option exists:

```
mikemike@x:~/workspace/resources/assets/sass (master) $ sass -h compass
Usage: sass [options] [INPUT] [OUTPUT]

Description:
  Converts SCSS or Sass files to CSS.

Common Options:
    -I, --load-path PATH             Specify a Sass import path.
    -r, --require LIB                Require a Ruby library before running Sass.
        --compass                    Make Compass imports available and load project configuration.
    -t, --style NAME                 Output style. Can be nested (default), compact, compressed, or expanded.
    -?, -h, --help                   Show this help message.
    -v, --version                    Print the Sass version.
```

I'm unsure how to get this working.  There is no additional information on it and simply running `sass --compass` or `sass --compass config.rb` just seems to put sass in interactive mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command you just ran is giving you a hint as to how you're supposed to use it.  It expects an input and an output.  Since you're providing neither, it goes into interactive mode.

You can't specify the location of the config.rb, this is by design.  Use the `compass` command instead (eg. `compass watch`).

> `sass --compass`  is intended to be a quick-and-dirty way to get access to the Compass libraries that don't require any configuration. If you want anything more complicated, you should use the  `compass`  executable.

https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/858